# iOS - Custom View Controller Example

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I've spent the morning looking for a good example of a code based (Not IB) custom view controller and I've not found a decent one that breaks the process down.

Does any one know of a good code based (not IB) custom view controller example? It would be ideal (but not necessary) if it would display an image when it loads.

Edit: For clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this code sample](http://icodesnip.com/snippet/objective-c/uiscrollview-with-3-images), it is a class derived from `UIViewController` that uses a UIScrollView to manage 3 UIImageViews.